# Issue with angular js 1.3.14

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a UI developer and new to angular js.
I am trying to update the value in the

Hello {{name}}

when entered in the input type text using angular js, but i am unable to do it without specifying the controller.

Can anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS First Application</title>
  <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sample Application</h1>
<p> Enter your Name <input  type ="text"  ng-model ="name"></p>
<p> Hello {{name}} ! </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to explain what your problem is and what you are trying to do. I can tell you now though that you need `ng-controller` for the model to work.

Comment: Trying to reflect the value entered in input to <p> Hello {{name}}</p>

Comment: Is it possible to do without ng-controller?.  Thanks Rob for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the changes I made here. Basically you need to actually run angular so it can do its magic

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('myctrl', function() {
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <title>AngularJS First Application</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller='myctrl'>
  <h1>Sample Application</h1>
  <p>Enter your Name
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  </p>
  <p>Hello {{name}} !</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. Is it possible to do with ng-controller.

Comment: You need all the code I provided.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Simon's response and answer your question, no it isn't doable without a controller ("ng-controller"). The controller tells Angular where and how to do it's magic. In the most basic example (like this) you declare the controller in both your HTML and Javascript and Angular binds them together, allowing you to share data back and forth between the two seamlessly.

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
      // This is where you can program logic for the scope of your controller 'myctrl'
      // For example, I could change the name here instead like this:
      $scope.name="My name defined in controller";

      // Or perhaps you want to create a function that is called upon the click of a button:
      $scope.changeName = function(newName){
          $scope.name = newName;
      }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <title>AngularJS First Application</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller='myctrl'> 
  <!-- Begin scope -->
  <h1>Sample Application</h1>
  <p>Enter your Name
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  </p>
  <p>Hello {{name}} !</p>

  <!-- Change name to "Name#2" when you click the button -->
  <input type="submit" ng-click="changeName('Name#2')"/>
  <!-- End scope -->
</body>
<!-- So if you tried to access the 'name' variable out here you wouldn't
     be able to because it is outside the scope of your controller -->  
</html>
```